# insert an empty spaces in between the array

Tags: matlab

I would like to insert an empty spaces in between an array (Matlab)

```
a = [1 2 3 4]
```

I would like to have an empty space at index 3 ( in between 2 and 3),
 `OR` I would move the `value 3 to 4th index and 4 to 5th index`

I want to create a grouped bar plot. So inorder to include separate 'Xticklabels' for every bars, I am concatenating all the Xticklabel values in a vector. Thus, from one group to another group there is an empty space and I want to avoid inserting the ticks in between the groups.

Edit: Additionally, let's suppose `a = [0 100 400 0 0 100 400 0 0 100 400 0 0]`, I need to replace all the zeros with `empty cells` in an output cell array.

Comment: You can't have an *empty space* in an array in Matlab.  I'm not sure it makes sense in Matlab, nor in any other programming language I am familiar with.  Why do you want this ?  Knowing why might help readers to help you achieve your aim without making possible the impossible, which can be quite tricky.

Comment: What do you mean by 'an empty space'? What's the end goal?

Comment: Would a `NaN` satisfy your need for empty space?   `b = [a(1:2) NaN a(3:4)];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this -

```
a_cell = mat2cell(a,1,ones(1,numel(a)))
a_cell(4:end+1) = a_cell(3:end)
a_cell{3} = ''
```

---

Edit -

```
 a = [0 100 400 0 0 100 400 0 0 100 400 0 0] 
 a_cell = mat2cell(a,1,ones(1,numel(a)))
 a_cell(a==0) = {''}
```